# PySpark group by into json column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have data like this:

```
PERSON_ID |   DATE_PT    | COL1 | COL2 | COL 3
=========================================
  1       |   2022-03-21 |   3  |   A  |  @
  1       |   2022-03-20 |   4  |   B  |  $
  1       |   2022-03-19 |   5  |   C  |  !
  1       |   2022-03-18 |   6  |   D  |  *
```

`DATE_PT` is date type, `COL1` is int, `Col2` and `Col3` are just string.

The final output I want is basically this:

```
PERSON_ID | AGG_JSON
======================
 1
```

Where the `AGG_JSON` would be:

```
{
    "MY_TITLE_STRING": "A LITERAL I ADDED",
    "TABLE_DATA": {
        "MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL1" : {
            '2022-03-21' : 3,
            '2022-03-20' : 4,
            '2022-03-19' : 5,
            '2022-03-18' : 6,
         },
         
         "MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL2" : {
            '2022-03-21' : A,
            '2022-03-20' : B,
            '2022-03-19' : C,
            '2022-03-18' : D,
         },
         
         "MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL3" : {
            '2022-03-21' : @,
            '2022-03-20' : $,
            '2022-03-19' : !,
            '2022-03-18' : *,
         }
    }
}
```

So basically I want to format it like this, it seems tricky and I am not 100% sure how I can go about it. I tried something like:

```
df = my_df.groupBy(f.col('PERSON_ID')).agg(
  f.to_json(
    f.create_map(
      f.lit('TABLE_DATA'),
      f.map_from_entries(
        f.collect_list(
          f.struct(...,...)
        )
      )
    )
    
  )
)
```

But this doesnt work and its very not pretty. I am thinking a UDF of some sort may work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = my_df.select('PERSON_ID', 
  F.struct('DATE_PT', 'COL1').alias('COL1'), 
  F.struct('DATE_PT', 'COL2').alias('COL2'),
  F.struct('DATE_PT', 'COL3').alias('COL3')).\
groupBy('PERSON_ID').agg(
  F.map_from_entries(F.collect_list('COL1')).alias('MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL1'),
  F.map_from_entries(F.collect_list('COL2')).alias('MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL2'),
  F.map_from_entries(F.collect_list('COL3')).alias('MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL3')).\
select('PERSON_ID', F.to_json(F.struct(F.struct(
  'MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL1', 
  'MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL2', 
  'MY_LITERAL_STRING_FOR_COL3').alias('TABLE_DATA'))).alias('AGG_JSON'))
```